# AS3 Remove child not working and or giving error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I want to do, basically is to remove the movie clip when it gets outside the stage.
But the removechild code is giving me errors (line 62). Help! 
I'm new at flash btw. Tips, or whatever are greatly appreciated!

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var tray:Array = new Array(Legal2_1,Legal2_2,Legal2_3,Legal2_4,Legal2_5,Legal2_6,Legal2_7,Legal2_8,Legal2_9,Legal2_10,Legal2_11,Legal2_12,Legal2_13,Legal2_14,Legal2_15,Illegal2_1,Illegal2_2,Illegal2_3,Illegal2_4,Illegal2_5,Illegal2_6,Illegal2_7,Illegal2_8,Illegal2_9,Illegal2_10,Illegal2_11,Illegal2_12,Illegal2_13,Illegal2_14,Illegal2_15);
var traypos:int;
var goodpos:int;
var badpos:int;

traypos = (stage.stageWidth / 2)-100;
goodpos = ((stage.stageWidth / 3) -100);
badpos = (((stage.stageWidth/3) *2) -100);

Score.text = score.toString();
Combo.text = combo.toString();

var timerT:Timer = new Timer(1000,120);
timerT.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, traytimerhandler);
timerT.start();

var secondsT:Number = 1;

function traytimerhandler(event:TimerEvent)
{
    //trace("Seconds elapsed: " + seconds);
    SpawnTray();
    secondsT++;
}

function SpawnTray():void
{
    var trayspawn:int;
    trayspawn = int(Math.random() * tray.length);

    //var trayn:MovieClip = new tray[trayspawn]();
    var trayn:MovieClip = new tray[trayspawn];
    trayn.trayTypeIndex = trayspawn;

    addChild(trayn);

    trayn.x = traypos;
    trayn.y = -20;

    trayn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);    
    trayn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);   
}

function MoveTray(event:Event):void
{   
var trayn:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
trayn.y +=  5;
/*if (trayn.y >= stage.stageHeight + 50)
{
    trayn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
    trayn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTwo);
    trayn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);    
    //removeChild(trayn);
    //tray.parent.removeChild(trayn);
}   */
if (trayn.y >= stage.stageHeight + 50)
{
    this.removeChild(trayn); //ERROR
}

}

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
    // surprise! This object will not be moved via MOUSE_DOWN,;
    // because it's already being moved 
    e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    e.target.startDrag();
}
// drag;

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
    e.target.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
    e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopDragging);
    return;// emergency exit. We don't need to do more
}
```

Comment: put error detail here Please

Comment: Error #1006: removeChild is not a function.

Comment: Also, do not use two `ENTER_FRAME` events unless if necessary.

Comment: The problem is that you are returning an anonymous function with your `moveTwo` function. Drop a breakpoint in that anonymous function and you'll see that `this` is not what you expect it to be. The fix is to change your approach, as you simply don't understand what is going on with this line - `trayn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTwo(trayspawn));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your `addChild(trayn);` is not working.

Why you are calling `SpawnTray(null);` if it needs to pass Event?

Either make `SpawnTray(event:Event)` as `SpawnTray()` like so,

```
function SpawnTray():void
{

    //I have not added your all lines here for clarity (you add it here)

    var trayn:MovieClip = tray[trayspawn]; //See this modified line


}
```

And modify `traytimerhandler` like so,

```
function function traytimerhandler(event:TimerEvent)
{
    //trace("Seconds elapsed: " + seconds);
    SpawnTray(); // modified
    secondsT++;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've modified both my SpawnTray and traytimerhandler function but sadly it didn't solve the error at line 96 which is ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

The code on that line is removeChild(trayn); on MoveTwo function.

Comment: You also need to rethink on this `trayn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTwo(trayspawn));`. You are adding two `ENTER_FRAME` events. Use just one and use vars (flags) to make decisions inside single `ENTER_FRAME`.

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda desperate when that's why I did two enter frames. Thanks, gonna play around with my code for now.

Comment: Btw the code you added in SpawnTray just caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

This line should work :

```
   trayn.parent.removeChild(trayn);
```

However, as I noted in my comment, it doesn't seem you understand what is really going on with your approach which is causing the confusion.

It's a bad approach, and what you need to do is take a step back and rethink why you want/need to pass a parameter to that handler function that is returned.

If it's a MovieClip one approach is that you can just add a property when creating to store a given value - ie:

```
trayn.trayTypeIndex = trayspawn;
```

Now wherever you are using that instance (if it's cast as a MovieClip) you can access that property.

An example might be something like this in your handler :

```
var trayn:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;

if (trayn.trayTypeIndex <= 14)
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is what I was looking for. Thanks man. Gonna implement this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how does typeindex works? I think one of the main problem in my code is the program is having a hard time distinguishing what is the array number of the tray which I think will be solved by this.

Comment: I've edited my code and made it simpler first. Now how do I remove the movie clip when it gets out of stage?

Comment: Does this line give you an error ? - `trayn.parent.removeChild(trayn);` If it does not, than it should be removed. Right ?

Comment: I just looked at your code and you changed it. As I was saying, you don't understand what is going on. The line of code I gave you at the top - would make it work WITHOUT my suggestion as a new approach.

Comment: With my new approach, you would just use `removeChild(trayn)` I didn't code the whole thing out, I gave you an example of how you could achieve the goal of having access to the trayTypeIndex. If you aren't grasping the fundamentals of scope and event handlers, it's best if you take the time to learn a bit about them before proceeding. I'm not going to code you a full solution.